# jQuery - find input have multiple class by part of class

Tags: jquery

I have HTML like this:

```
<input type="text"  name="hyouka_sha1_bi" class="class1 class2 ... classIWantToGet_1" ></td>
<input type="text"  name="hyouka_sha1_bi" class="class1 class2 ... classIWantToGet_2" ></td>
```

I want to get all `input` that has class name which starts with `"classIWantToGet_"`.

I tried to use:

```
$('#template_body_new_doc').find(':input[class^=\'classIWantToGet_\']')
```

But I can't get any elements. It only works if my input has one class name.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [contains with selector of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
$('#template_body_new_doc').find(':input[class*="classIWantToGet_"]')
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jd2qq4j4/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can to use the [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
$('#template_body_new_doc').find(':input[class*="classIWantToGet_"]')
```

Note: This may not work if there is another class that contains the given string in its middle or end

Answer (score 0):

For any number of classes, in below code, border will apply to all inputs who has class name starts with "classIWantToGet_".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[class^='classIWantToGet'],input[class*=' classIWantToGet_']").css("border","1px solid");
    })
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/dzLg0msn/) is demo jsfiffle

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the working demo

In this example If input has a class starting with "classIWantToGet_" I am adding border for those input elements.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/silpa/a4s4m252/8/

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$("input[class*='classIWantToGet']").css("border","1px solid red");
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joL5zboa/14/)